# Get last emitted object from multiple sources

Tags: rxjs

To be more specific, I don't want an array of emitted object.  I want the last object emitted by either source.

Currently, it's working like this

```
.withLatestFrom(subject1, subject2)
.switchMap([val1, val2]) => {...}
```

What I want is

```
.withLatestFrom(subject1, subject2)
.switchMap(latestVal) => {...}
```

To avoid a possible x=y problem.  What I have is two subjects.  Subject1 and Subject2.

If subject2 has emitted any values, that value will always trump subject1. In my use case once subject 2 has started emitted, this particular module will ignore subject 1.  But subject 1 will be used elsewhere.

But I want a way to feed these two subjects as sources and either get the last emitted value, or the last value of subject 2 if it's not null.  If subject 2 is null then get the last value from subject 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that I think does what you are looking for:

```js
const first = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(x => `first (${x})`);
const second = Rx.Observable.interval(2000).map(x => `second (${x})`);

Rx.Observable.merge(
  first.takeUntil(second),
  second
)
.subscribe(
  x => { console.log('next: ', x); },
  null,
  () => { console.log('complete'); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The `takeUntil` will cause the "first" observable to stop emitting values for this subscription the first time the "second" observable emits.

Comment: That's my fault.  I missed a detail.  The other observable will be used by other sections of the application.  So I don't want it to stop emitting.  But for this specific use I want to combine both observables into one.  I have it working, but it's sloppy and not really reusable.

Comment: @Smeegs I think that it does what you want. The `takeUntil` operator will stop the first observable from continuing to emit for that subscription. If you have other active subscriptions then they will continue to receive values from the first observable.

Comment: gotcha.  I think this should do what I need.  Thanks.  One last question.  Merge will not affect any other subscribers to either observable.  it will just create a new observable is that correct?

Comment: @Smeegs yeah, it won't affect any subscriptions directly to the first or second observable.